# Send a 2D array through topics in ROS2

Tags: ros, ros2, messages, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is a proper way of sending 2D arrays through topics? I want to send small ones (4x6 for example) and so far I created an array msg (float64[]) and then use the .reshape function in order to send it as an unidimensional array. However, I do not know if there is a better way.

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364269/send-a-2d-array-through-topics-in-ros2/) by [jeferrandiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/60816/jeferrandiz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2020-10-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yep I think your approach is good enough. You define an one dimensional array in msg and after you receive the msg in your callback you restructure this as a 2D array.
One thing I can recommend though is that you add 2 additional fields such as width and height to your msg description, and when you recive your msg you can know the correct dimensions by receiving `width` and `height`

A good use case will be to check how [sensor_msgs::Image](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html) do this by something similar;

---

Originally posted by [Fetullah Atas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32821/fetullah-atas/) with karma: 819 on 2020-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1